# Performant way to limit selected rows but make sure the sum of the rows is large enough

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, running-totals

Here's a simplified version of the problem. You have a marketplace where users can publish how many items they have for sale and the price. You would like to buy 1 000 000 items, and you want to purchase the cheapest listings first.

Example of getting all rows:

```
SELECT id, price, count FROM for_sale ORDER BY price ASC
```

In a worst-case scenario, you might need to fetch 1 000 000 rows if each user is selling one item each, but usually, users would publish more than a single item.

Is there a performant way to get only the rows needed to fulfil the purchase? E.g., for each row, a counter named `total_items` is incremented with `count`, and when `total_items` covers the wanted purchase amount, no more rows are returned.

Using `LIMIT` reduces the number of rows returned, but I can't be sure how many rows are needed as it depends on each row's count.

### What I've tried so far

```
SET @total := 0;
SELECT id, count, price, @total := @total + count AS total
FROM for_sale
WHERE @total < 1000000 ORDER BY `price` ASC;
```

This query somewhat works, but the user variable check seems to be done client-side resulting in up to seven additional rows where the total is over 1 000 000. The performance is also terrible compared to just a `LIMIT`(more than 300x execution time).

I've also tried to use a window function, but I'm not sure if that's possible without reading the whole table.

Is there a way to only select rows that covers the purchase amount instead of every row? I've searched a lot, and the only examples I've found is user variable ones that suffer from performance issues.

Comment: that is a misconception the user variable is only run in the server never the client. as long as the session is open you can access this variable

Comment: I think you wanted `ORDER BY price ASC`.

Comment: What's the reason why `total` might be larger than X when using `total` < X and the batch like behaviour where rows seem to be received in groups of eight then? I'd love to know what's going on.

Comment: See if any of the `[running-totals]` links helps.  You do have "windowing functions" that were introduced in 10.2 -- one of them should be handy.

Comment: @RickJames I've already searched a lot without finding anything. I know about and tried window functions but found no solution that limited the rows used to the needed ones. Is there any way to stop a window function early? Isn't it just one big step? I could run a basic(but fast) query to fetch X rows, check the total sum and fetch more if needed from code. But that seems like a really hacky solution and would also result in terrible performance due to round trip latency. It would be really great to do it serverside, but I can't find any good examples online.

Comment: @Alex - Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61284912/mariadb-running-total-up-to-n-and-rows-not-included-in-its-calculation

Comment: @Alex - and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200598/get-rows-from-table-whose-sum-is-less-than-value

Comment: another:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262798/sql-how-to-find-top-customers-that-pay-80-of-revenue

Comment: (Note that stackoverflow.com is a better place for SQL query questions.)

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for the tips, but I've seen some of them before, and none of them solves the issue. The problem isn't the counting. The problem is to avoid full table scans while doing it. All solutions I've found so far adds up all rows and then selects those with a value within the wanted range. That isn't usable with millions of rows when only a few rows are needed in most cases. I'll try StackOverflow too.

Comment: @Alex - Yeah, I would not be surprised that they have not optimized for your case.  MySQL 8.0 has similar windowing functions, but (I think) independently implemented.  So it may do better.  Here is a technique to 'prove' that it is (or is not) being inefficient:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts